# performance of pthread_cond_broadcast when no one is waiting on condition

Tags: linux, performance, pthreads, condition-variable, nptl

If I call pthread_cond_broadcast and no one is waiting on the condition, will the pthread_cond_broadcast invoke a context switch and/or call to kernel?

If not, can I rely on it being very fast (by fast I mean, just running a small number of assmebly instruction in current process and then returning)?

Comment: What about using measuring it yourself using a profiler, then come back and have us discuss the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no guarantees in POSIX, but since your question is tagged <kbd>linux</kbd> and <kbd>nptl</kbd> an answer in that context can be given.

If there are no waiters on the condition variable, then the [nptl glibc code for `pthread_cond_broadcast()`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_cond_broadcast.c;h=0702ec0ec2bb644867c63cf38a2f122d73925ad9;hb=HEAD) just takes a low-level lock protecting the internals of the condition variable itself, tests a value then unlocks the low-level lock.  The low-level lock itself uses a futex, which will only enter the kernel if there is contention on that lock.

This means that unless there is a lot of contention on the condition variable itself (ie. a large number of threads frequently calling `pthread_cond_broadcast()` / `pthread_cond_signal()` on the same condition variable) there will be no system call to the kernel, and the overhead will only be a few locked instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The `pthread` Open Group Base Specifications states:

> The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` and `pthread_cond_signal()` functions shall have no effect if there are no threads currently blocked on `cond`.

To get a measure of whether or not this takes "just running a small number of assmebly [*sic*] instruction" you'll have to get out some run-time performance-analysis tool (e.g IBM's Quantify) and run it against your code.